# Unable to open the docker shell on minicube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am running minikube instance on window 10 machine. I've tried to open the docker shell, but docker wasn't recognized in the cmd.

```
C:\tools\cloud>.\minikube.exe docker-env --shell cmd
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://172.27.61.204:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\sswain\.minikube\certs
SET DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.35
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO @%i
```

As the instruction specifies I again run the command provided in the instruction.

```
C:\tools\cloud>REM @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO @%i    
C:\tools\cloud>
```

It didn't open the docker shell.

Comment: Remove the `REM ` prefix from the command.

Comment: I tried all possible option but unable to see the docker shell.C:\tools\cloud>@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('C:/tools/cloud/minikube.exe docker-env') DO @%i

Comment: I am using cmd instead of powershell. Could that be a issue?

Comment: Try to use GitBash (https://git-scm.com/download/win).

Comment: Should I install docker CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands you get from `minikube.exe docker-env --shell cmd` does not start any shell, but they configure your Docker CLI to access Docker from Minikube.

In my case, I tried CMD with the following:

```
C:\Users\rafal>minikube.exe docker-env --shell cmd
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.0.24:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\rafal\.minikube\certs
SET DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.35
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube docker-env') DO @%i
```

After executing all the commands above, I could access the Docker Engine with Docker CLI.

```
C:\Users\rafal>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  
CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
9736b43b6cd5        k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64           "/sidecar --v=2 --lo…"   
About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_sidecar_kube-dns- 
86f4d74b45-pb6k7_kube-system_0da3947c-aa9d-11e8-8305-00155d395166_0
3640c6aa2e73        k8s.gcr.io/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64     "/dnsmasq-nanny -v=2…"   
About a minute ago   Up About a minute                       k8s_dnsmasq_kube-dns- 
86f4d74b45-pb6k7_kube-system_0da3947c-aa9d-11e8-8305-00155d395166_0
...
```

Note that `minikube.exe` must be on your env PATH, since otherwise `'minikube docker-env'` may not be executed correctly.

Comment: That means I need to install a docker CLI or docker on window and from the cmd I should point to the docker demon running inside minicube VM.